# Telerik Data Access generate classes automatically

Tags: visual-studio, orm, telerik, telerik-open-access

Until the recent release I was happily using Telerik Data Access in a database first way:

- Created the database schema in external DB designer
- Generated a fluent model in Visual Studio
- Whenever I did a database change I either re-ran the generation or updated models via visual designer depending on the magnitude of the change

After the last release the templates I used for the generation are gone (as is the visual designer) and any attempt at Googling the solution takes me to a Telerik documentation page saying the info is deprecated.

I'm working with large existing databases (100+ tables) and there's no way I'm coding the models by hand.

What are the current options for auto generating the models?

Comment: ...and you've stumbled upon one of my pet peeves with Telerik.  They are good for changing things with very little warning.  My best advice would be to roll back to the previous version for now (if this is viable), until you can find a better solution.

Comment: That's another thing. I can't seem to go back. When I install the earlier version of their tools the templates don't reappear. Not to mention that there's no Visual Studio 2015 support. But maybe I missed a step, need to look again.

Comment: Ok a PC reboot helped and I successfully reverted. Nevertheless, going forward I'm still on a lookout for a way to generate the models automatically. The lack of VS 2015 support is a deal breaker here.

Answer (score 1):

I got a reply on Telerik forums. Simply said there's nothing I can do now and have to wait til/if they develop a solution. For all that are interested, please vote on the feature request.

Here's the reply:

Thank you for your feedback.
We have already created a new feature request (http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/114/Feedback/Details/163155-generation-of-fluent-models-with-data-access-q2-2015-and-higher) to create a code generating tool to create your fluent models based on your database schema. You are welcome to cast your support vote for the item.
I cannot give you any time frame when we will be able to ship such tool, but I will make sure to notify you as soon as we have a public release.

Regards,
Viktor Zhivkov 
Telerik

Answer (score 0):

The feature is still not available. But maybe this is an alternative to being stuck with VisualStudio 2013.

Owners of VisualStudio Enterprise have another option. They can modify the code generation templates and generate the fluent metadata and context code from an UML class diagram.

I invested in checking the MSDN documentation and created a VS extension which I open-sourced.

Please check https://github.com/bdongus/UMLExtensions for details. Feel free contribute.